# How many things called stack are there?

Tags: assembly, data-structures, x86

How many different things called "stack" are there, and how do they relate to one another? And if someone says "the stack" can I reasonably assume they mean one of these, or can I only figure it out from context?

But first, I would just like to give an overview of what my understanding is at this point.

There seems to be an awful lot of vaguely related things in programming that are all called "a stack", "the stack", or something of the sort. Aside from the data-structure, I am not even sure if the term refers to the same thing or different things.

Based on [this page](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Disassembly/Functions_and_Stack_Frames) it seems like "the stack" is not even a stack data-structure. While you do only put things on top of it, you can access any element from the stack without having to pop off all the elements before it. Unless I am completely misunderstanding the data-structure. Before I read this, the idea of using a stack as a data-structure for variables seemed like a really bad decision.

Then there's the issue with "the stack", a call stack, and the hardware stack. I figure that the hardware stack is the call stack, because you can put instructions in it (?), but it couldn't possibly also be the place you store your fixed-size variables. Or is it? Why does a stack even have to be implemented in the hardware? I thought variables were stored in RAM and not the processor's memory. Or is the call stack language specific, and thus not hardware?

Then there's the stack frame, which seems to be a general thing for all stacks, except for the data-structure.

I can't figure out how to google this properly, because I am never sure if people are talking about the same thing. The more I try to understand, the more I get confused

Comment: Last time I counted, back in 1987, there were 142, but there could be more by now.

Comment: Seriously though a stack is just a *concept* - there is only one such concept, but there are many different implementations and contexts in which this concept is used. They are all referred to as stacks though, because that is the underlying concept. Whenever the term might be ambiguous then it needs to be qualified to make it clear what sort of realisation of a stack is being referred to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR**
*When we allow programs to call subroutines, we need to keep track of the **call stack** (as explained below). This can be implemented in a variety of ways limited only by your creativity, but the simplest and fastest ways is a pointer that get incremented or decremented each time we push/pop something. Since this is so easy to implement and so used, a CPU can provide instructions and registers that remove boilerplate code (and can be optimized). That is the **hardware stack**.*

---

### The need for a stack structure

A stack is any structure that support the *LIFO* paradigm.

There is no intrinsic need for the CPU to provide support for a stack (MIPS don't do that for example), but you will anyway end up using it.

To understand why, simply consider the mere act of **calling a subroutine**.

When calling a subroutine, we need to remember its return address.
Even if the CPU stores the address in a register, say *$ra*, the problem is that the callee may need to call another subroutine itself!
So we need to first save *$ra* and then make the new call.
Again this new callee may need to make another call, and the problem repeat, potentially **infinite times**.

If you think about it, you will realize that:

1. We need to remember every return address and their order.
2. On return we will consume these addresses from the last one to the first.

This is *LIFO* behavior, we need a stack, hence the name **call stack**.

---

### Implementing the call stack

How the stack is actually implemented is architecture defined, if the CPU is general purpose it is unlikely that some form of internal, non accessible, memory is used. We already have access to the RAM, so why not using it? This way we impose no internal limit on the depth of the recursion.

In assembly everything is made up by its use.
We don't need complex meta data to implement a stack, just a simple **pointer**.
It's up to the programmer make sure it will never pop a time more than it pushed or to make sure the new pushed element won't overwrite something.

Most assembly programmers ends up using a register for keeping track of the head of the stack.
Since this is a universally implemented technique, CISC CPUs have dedicated registers and instruction for managing the stack.

1. You can push/pop an operand on the stack, using the implicit stack pointer.
2. A call will push the return address on the stack, using the implicit stack pointer.
3. A return will pop the return address (and jump to it) on the stack, using the implicit stack pointer.

This is the **hardware stack** if you want to use that name.

**You are not so free to pick up an implementation**, since your program isn't usually running on its own on bare metal, you need to stick to the ABI with dictate how the stack is implemented.

### Not so stack

Assembly programming is like quantum physic, it is the programmer (observer) that dictate the nature of the things.

Since a program can freely access its RAM, all the above stack operations can be reimplemented without using the dedicated instructions.
If the stack pointer is accessible to the programmer (and it should be or we won't be able to set the stack up in the first place) we can use it as a base pointer and cheat on the stack structure accessing elements not on top.

This is ordinary assembly programming. Everything is defined by use, not by fixed rules.

**Note** that we cannot *remove* element not on top, since the only thing that define the stack is its head pointer, every property of the stack is defined by that pointer.
Including its size.

### Other uses of the stack

A consolidated convention is to use the stack to also store subroutines parameters (if we already have filled all the registers) and local variables.

This is due to a very interesting property of the stack: it is very easy to allocate/free memory on the stack.
Just move the pointer back and forth.
It is assumed that the stack pointer points to some memory area large enough for common purpose, you can think of it as an *already allocated chunk of memory* and that everything behind of the stack pointer is in use (while everything ahead can be suddenly be overwritten).

If you rethink about the call stack you'll find out that this is the natural way of doing the things.
When a new subroutine is called, new space on the stack is allocated by altering the stack pointer, when it return, that space is freed, restoring the stack pointer.
The caller will always have its data at the same relative location with respect of the stack pointer.

Also each routine see its data (and parameters) at the very end of the stack, independently on how many calls have been done before.

Comment: I see. Very thorough answer, your formatting makes this an easy read.

Would you say that either **A**: The hardware stack and the call stack are the same thing? or **B**: The name "hardware stack" refers to a set of abstractions that allow for ease of use of the call stack? Or at least something along those directions?

Also, does this mean that the call stack contains both the data the subroutines use, as well as a pointer to the subroutines themselves? Thus making it the responsibility of an assembly programmer to make sure not to try to jump to some random address accidentally?

Comment: @MrNosco: yes, the "hardware stack" and "call stack" are the same thing.  In practice nobody says "the hardware stack"; that's just Margaret's way of making it clear she's talking about the stack that the CPU's stack-pointer register points to.  **B**: yes, when writing asm by hand, it's easy to have bugs like running a `ret` instruction when `%rsp` is pointing to some data you pushed, rather than to the return address pushed by a previous `call` instruction.  Seach the [tag:x86] and/or [tag:assembly] questions for many examples of newbie questions where this is the problem :P