# Is there a difference between data structure stack and hardware stack?

Tags: data-structures, callstack

I've debated with my friend about the difference between data structure stack and hardware stack(call stack). I thought they are perfectly same because they both have 'push' and 'pop' that can deal with only the latest element. But my friend said that they're not same at all, but they share only the same name, 'stack'. And he thinks so because in call stack, we can access addresses that are not the latest ones, contradicting the definition of stack(data structure). Can you give an answer to this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How many things called stack are there?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35968024/how-many-things-called-stack-are-there)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some differences:

- Usually you can only have one hardware stack (per thread).
- You can have as many software stacks as desired.
- Usually hardware stack is managed by the CPU directly.
- Software stack access is managed explicitly from the code.
- Hardware stack is usually directly related to call stack (caller functions, their arguments).
- Software stack is independent of the hardware call stack (you can push item in a function and pop them in another one independently of hardware stack level).
- Hardware stack memory is managed bu the OS or CPU (might be limited).
- Software stack memory is managed by the application.

Well basically both stack have **push** and **pop** operations and thus work like a stack.

It would be possible to have pure or not pure hardware or software stack. Usually, hardware stack would be able to access items at a relative position from the top for arguments. On software stack, usually the protection would essentially be a private access.

On some embedded device, the stack might serve only for returns addresses and a software based stack might be needed for arguments. On some device, the maximum level can be very low.

Answer (score 0):

The first is a data structure and the second is a data structure applied.

Like most applications of data structures in the real world it's not pure and has features added for convenience or speed.